# How to make angular html5 routing to work with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, angular, routes

Hey I'm integrating an angular 6+ app into a web page created by wordpress.
I have made it that the app is running and everything, but can't seem to solve the issue where when you open a route of the angular app by clicking on a link outside wordpress or pasting the url in the address bar, wordpress says 404.

I have it like so:

```
http://example.com/angularApp // This url opens fine
```

angularApp is a page created by WP (I have hosted scripts and styles in there)

When I try to open http://example.com/angularApp/somecustom route Wordpress tells me that there is nothing on that url.

I saw that I need to use some kind of rewriting but could not get a good example. Can you please help me?

Comment: Your (currently not working) url should be redirected to the index.html of your app.

Comment: I don't have an index.html. I have hosted the scripts and styles in a wordpress page. I need to redirect to that page but I have no idea how. Can you give me an example please.

Comment: How did you get the base URL to work?  I am having some trouble figuring out how to get a submenu in wordpress admin to route to a specific angular app component (route).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the rewrite rule into the `functions.php` file located in the theme folder which made it work.

I have the following code added to the `function et_setup_theme()`:

```
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic_angularApp');

    function custom_rewrite_basic_icoranker() {
       add_rewrite_rule(
         'angularAppRoute',
         'index.php?page_id=116414',
         'top'
         );
     }
```

where `angularAppRoute` is the page route that I have hosted my angular app into.

`http://example.com/angularAppRoute`

Hope this helps someone else as well.